# Помогите разобраться с папкой ресурсов spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

В dispatcher-context.xml есть следующее:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>
```

Эта папка у меня создана.

Пробовал и так: `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>` с целью попасть в `src/main/resources`.

В контроллере сделал вот что:

```
  @RequestMapping("/www")
    public String www() throws IOException{
        File file = new File("/resorces/www.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
```

Во всех случаях появляется ошибка:

```
java.io.IOException: Системе не удается найти указанный путь
java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
```

Как ее убрать?

Comment: А что ты хочешь сделать?

Comment: @RuslanMasgutov я хочу через контроллер создать файл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mapping который ты указал он распространяется на web. Для получения файла в контролере используй класслоадер

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("www.txt").getFile());
```

Comment: спасибо, но я хочу создать файл.

Comment: Создавать файл в resource папки не есть хорошая практика так как после сборки проекта в jar/war ты не сможешь сохранять файлы в *resources/* так что для этих целей используй папку вне проекта

Comment: понял, спасибо.